# Executing a python file makes hardware freeze, in spite of free memory

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory, scikit-learn

A python file for performing data science loads approximately 200-300 MB into the memory. Then it runs several scikit-learn methods, in particular `linear_model.LogisticRegression` on it. The sample size is 60,000, the feature dimension is about 100. My PC has 16 GB RAM. I have the latest stable Ubuntu LTS. When executing the program, I monitor the RAM usage via free -m -s 5, so the numbers are to be updated every 5 seconds. When the data have been loaded by the program, the RAM usage is at 2 GB, there are still 14 GB shown to be free. However, the program freezes when executing one of the `fit` methods.

Freezing means: the fan is getting louder, the program does no more write into .csv files, the mouse does no more react, nor the keyboard - however, the memory monitor in the second command line window still operates and updates every five seconds. I was only able to react via (violent) reboot. What can be the reason, what the remedy? Perhaps `linear_model.LogisticRegression` cannot handle large sample sizes? In fact I tried a sample size of 1,000, and it worked without problem.

```
    X_test, Yp_test, Yd_test = preprocess_data(sort='test',d=2)
    X_train,Yp_train,Yd_train = preprocess_data(sort='train',d=2)
    with open('results_d={}.csv'.format(d), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow('Format: Method; example (left=prediction, right=true value); score for (training) data fit; score for test data fit (generalisation).')
        # RIDGE CLASSIFIER
        writer.writerow('Ridge regression')
        print('Ridge regression')
        ridge = linear_model.RidgeClassifier()
        print('#')
        ridge.fit(X_train,Yd_train)
        print('#')
        sc_fit = ridge.score(X_train,Yd_train)
        print('#')
        sc_gen = ridge.score(X_test,Yd_test)
        print('#')
        writer.writerow('Example (left=prediction, right=true value):')
        writer.writerows(np.transpose(np.array([ridge.predict(X_test[:50]),Yd_test[:50]])))
        writer.writerow("Mean accuracy = "+str(sc_fit)+str(sc_gen))
        # LOGISTIC REGRESSION
        writer.writerow('Log. regression')
        print('Log. regression')
        logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
        print('#')
        logreg.fit(X_train,Yd_train)
        print('#')
        sc_fit = logreg.score(X_train,Yd_train)
        print('#')
        sc_gen = logreg.score(X_test,Yd_test)
        print('#')
        writer.writerow('Example (left=prediction, right=true value):')
        writer.writerows(np.transpose(np.array([logreg.predict(X_test[:50]),Yd_test[:50]])))
        writer.writerow("Mean accuracy = "+str(sc_fit)+str(sc_gen))
```

EDIT: `ulimit -a` gives

```
<pre>core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63526
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63526
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
</pre>
```

Comment: Do you notice any curiosities with `ulimit -a` or `earlyoom` settings?

Comment: No, I don't see anything. Do you? I printed the ```ulimit -a``` printout in the post above. I also changed the code so that the data is written into a csv file. but after freezing and rebooting, the file's content stops before the output "after" reg.fit(...). Can this be a CPU problem? It is an AMD Ryzen 5 3400g.

Comment: I made more tests and found out the following. in fact, here "freezing" means more precisely: the fan is getting louder, the program does no more write into .csv files, the mouse does no more react, nor the keyboard - however, the program continues to provide print output, the memory monitor in the second command line window still operates and updates every five seconds. I was only able to react via (violent) reboot.

Comment: I do have some `ulimit -a` differences, but IDK if they are significant.  My "core file size" is "unlimited" and my "max locked memory" is 64 (several orders of magnitude smaller than yours).  My colleague also has a Ryzen 5 and has been quite happy with it.
Rather than `free` perhaps `vmstat -w 1` might show a sudden system stress?
It won't be fun wading through the output, but `strace` could be used to monitor system calls during execution.

Comment: Oh yeah, did you really want `linear_model.Ridge` rather than `linear_model.RidgeClassifier`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. In the meanwhile I have found out that the problem always originated in the fit method for the *LogisticRegression* method of linear model from sklearn. I did not see this in the beginning due to the freezing and because the prints and warning messages were not always in the right order. I used a sample size of 60,000, with feature size of around 100. When I decreased the sample size to 1,000, there was no problem. Is it true that sklearn Logistic Regression cannot handle data sets of that size? I replaced this SGDClassifier with 'log' loss; it worked for 60,000 data.

Comment: I used ```linear_model.RidgeClassifier```, but the problem was not there as mentioned in the comment above. I'll update the code correspondingly.

Comment: I wonder if your system is just under heavy load and perhaps could respond better with some tuning. If you run the problematic `fit` with the `python` process having a hefty `nice` factor, does the overall system responsiveness improve?